# How to modify feature in data table if it already created in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

```
 //Dynamic or common Function
  $("#example").dataTable(
 {
  "aoColumnDefs": [{
  "bSortable": false, 
  "aTargets": [-1]
}]});
```

i want to do bSortable on different columns and i can't  change these function its sure .. provide me another ways in javascript... to achieve my result

Answer (score 0):

`"aTargets"` is the target sorting column, if for examples you want to disable the first &  third column, you could change the value to :

```
"aTargets": [0, 2]
```

Comment: in question i mentioned i can't change table definition.. only after creating table can change something ..i want to remove sorting  from some of column after creating datatable                                                      
$('#tbl').dataTable().fnSettings().aoColumns[7].bSortable = false; its working fine its disabled functionality of sorting but still i can see its symbol so i want to hide these symbol as well